# How can I send custom data to JQuery click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-events

I have this JQuery click event:

```
jq("#generateButton").click({key: "hello world"}, function () {
            console.dir(this);// this is the "generateButton" html element. 
        // jq(this) would be the jquery object of the generate button
            frnConstr.setDataObject(this);
        frnConstr.gameObject.state.start(frnConstr.EnteriorScreen.KEY);
    });
```

How could I possibly send custom data to this event, for example print {key: "hello world"}? 
Is it at all possible?

Note: In my custom made working environment jq() is $() or jquery().

Note: jQuery docs say that eventData can be anything, here's the official doc:
https://api.jquery.com/click/ :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally you would use the data attribute for this and grab it with

```
jq("#generateButton").on("click",function() {
  var custom = $(this).data("custom");
});
```

using

```
<button id="generateButton" data-custom="hello world">
```

You are referring to [event.data](https://api.jquery.com/event.data/) which is sent at bind time

```
jq("#generateButton").on("click",{"what":"hello"}, function(event) {
  var custom = $(this).data("custom");
  console.log(event.data.what+" "+custom); // hello world
});

<button id="generateButton" data-custom="world">
```

---

Examples

```js
$(function() {
  $("#generateButton1").on("click", function() {
    var custom = $(this).data("custom");
    console.log(custom);
  });


  $("#generateButton2").on("click", {
    what: "goodbye"
  }, function(event) { // needed here
    var custom = $(this).data("custom");
    console.log(event.data.what + " " + custom); // hello world
  });

  $("#generateButton3").on("click", function() {
    var formdata = $(this).closest("form").serialize();
    console.log(formdata);
  });
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="generateButton1" data-custom="hello world">Hello world</button>

<button type="button" id="generateButton2" data-custom="world">Goodbye world</button>
<hr/>
Serializing:
<form>
  <input type="text" name="field1" value="f1" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="field2" value="f2" /><br/>
  <button type="button" id="generateButton3">Click to serialize</button>
</form>
```

Comment: it is just a generate button that is just executing a function. The inner workings do the rest.

Comment: How would you send form data array serialized with JQuery to the click event if "this" object is the generateButton itself? Access parents? :)

Comment: Sure: $(this).closest("form").serialize()

Comment: @Vlad I am still surprised about your choice of accepted answer. It was 15 minutes later than mine and has no running example and seems not to answer what you really want to know - which seems to have changed in the mean time :)

Comment: Moar points please :P I have been busy with debugging my code. And the only thing I could utilize is $(this).closest("form").serialize() which is not in your answer. And yes I will not bind data structures with my generate button. It should just run a function. But don't worry, I am sure many people will find your answer useful, myself as well in future. The top answer is much cleaner. Send event data, plus event object inside the handler and there you have it.

Comment: As you can see I do not need points. I did however post `jq("#generateButton").on("click",{"what":"hello"}, function(event) {` and the link to the documentation along with an example a while before longestwayround did. Then I hung around to see if you needed more help and updated my question accordingly. If you see my updates, I have given an example of that too

Comment: Ok. your answer is more on documentation. The above one is more like a hack :) http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: All my examples work and are not hacks. Strange discussion :/

Comment: Pff, I meant the answer written by @longestwayround

Answer (score 1):

You can't but a way around is to have a data attribute in your html and get that attribute on click of that element.

eg:

```
 <button id="generateButton" data-key="something"/>

jq("#generateButton").click(function () {
    console.log($(this).data('key')); // something
    .....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you are reference jquery version 1.4.3 or higher.

```
jq("#generateButton").click({key: "hello world"}, function (event) {
    var key=event.data.key;
    //do something with the key value
});
```

All data passed in this eventData signature are accessible in the event.data object.

Comment: Apart from the version, what is not already mentioned in my answer? Event.data was added in 1.1 btw

Comment: Yes I have latest JQuery version.